# How can I install the latest version of GROMACS?

Tags: software-center

The version of GROMACS available in the Ubuntu Software Center? is not the latest available version.

How can I install the latest version of GROMACS without using the Ubuntu Software Center?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of waiting, you can download the latest [Gromacs](http://www.gromacs.org/Downloads), and install it.  Once downloaded, make sure that you have all the prerequisites met, and just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, navigate to where the file was downloaded (probably the Downloads folder), run the command(s) below:

```
tar xfz gromacs-4.6.1.tar.gz
cd gromacs-4.6.1
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DGMX_BUILD_OWN_FFTW=ON
make
sudo make install
```

For more detailed info, and how to meet the prerequisites, see the [Installation Instructions](http://www.gromacs.org/Documentation/Installation_Instructions#GROMACS_installation_guide)

Comment: Thanks. This is a 'quick and dirty' installation. Somebody please upload the latest version of GROMACS in UBUNTU software center.